# swiftで構造体の配列をDictionaryに変換する方法について

Tags: ios, swift

Swiftで構造体の配列をDictionaryに変換したいのですが、
スマートに変換することは可能でしょうか？

```
struct Employee {
    var Id: String!
    var Name: String!
    var Salary: String!
}

var emps = [Employee]()
emps.append(Employee(Id: "111", Name: "222", Salary: "333"))
emps.append(Employee(Id: "AAA", Name: "BBB", Salary: "CCC"))
```

下記のようなDictionaryに変換結果がなることを期待します。

```
let params = ["emps":[["Id": "111", "Name": "222", "Salary": "333"],["Id": "AAA", "Name": "BBB", "Salary": "CCC"]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

あなたの言うスマートが何かを定義しなければ答えづらいです。
私なら構造体に変換するための関数を定義します。

```
struct Employee {
    var Id: String!
    var Name: String!
    var Salary: String!
    func toDictionary() -> [String: String!] {
        return [
            "Id" : Id,
            "Name" : Name,
            "Salary" : Salary,
        ]
    }
}

let params = [
    "emps": emps.map{e in e.toDictionary()}
]
```

Comment: まさにこれです。Arrayにmapという便利な機能が備わっていることを知りませんでした。ありがとうございます。